# Bags collection, Bag collection or Bag collections

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

> 1. She is showcasing her designer bags collection.

> 2. She is showcasing her knitted bag collection

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

For the second sentence, I'm thinking if I should use ***bag*** instead of ***bags*** because they are of the same nature. While the first sentence refer to more than one designer's bags and hence a ***bags** collection*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's her designer bag collection or her collection of designer bags.

Typically, when we use a noun as an adjective in front of another noun (a noun adjunct), the first noun is used in the singular.

Dog kennels, pony stables, car parts, bicycle shop and so on.

There are some exceptions, as in sports gear, which you just have to learn.

[Plural or singular noun adjunct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/160983/plural-or-singular-noun-adjunct)

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1: "She is showcasing her designer bags collection." is incorrect.

She can be showcasing her her "collection of designer bags", where they are countable objects, or her "bag collection", where the collection is of the type "designer bag", no distinction between designers, bag type etc.. It is not very idiomatic to clarify that the designers are different here.

Sentence 2 : "She is showcasing her knitted bag collection" is fine for the reasons above.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that singular "bag" is more grammatically correct in both cases. "Collection" implies group so (*plural*)(*group*) is doubling up.

"Bag collection" could also be considered a single term.