# why "study selections" and not "stud(ies) selections"

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

It is very confusing for me to write **study selections** instead of **studies selections** when I am referring to a group of studies. I am an Arabic native and we two plural in a noun phrase.

Can anyone please explain why this would be incorrect in English grammar?

Comment: In the same way that you would have "one study group" or "two study groups". The noun 'study' is a sort-of adjective in the noun phrase, but we don't pluralise adjectives.

Comment: if the study is the adjective, the selection is what exactly?

Comment: It isn't an adjective, it is forming the role of one. What do *you* mean by "study selections"?

Comment: Study selections is a step of including studies in a review.

Comment: They are both nouns, but only the main subject is pluralised, not the qualifying noun.

Comment: The cited usage has ***study*** as a ***noun adjunct, attributive noun***, adjectivally modifying the "head" noun ***selections***. With very few exceptions, attributive nouns are almost always ***singular***, not plural.

Comment: Also highly relevant: [Plural or singular noun adjunct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/160983/plural-or-singular-noun-adjunct#:~:text=In%20summary%3A,never%20sells%20an%20%22arm.%22) Note that plural "attributive nouns" such as ***an arms dealer, a boys club, a sports centre,...*** are very much the exception.

Comment: I am afraid study selections is incorrect in the context you mention. We would say study selection in the singular for the process of selecting them and selected studies if we want to talk about the result of the selection.